# Why can't I just do git push after creating remote repo?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Creating a new GitHub repo is super simple. On the command line:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Then you go into GitHub and create your repo, which creates a Git URL for it, say, `https://github.com/<myuser>/<myRepo>.git`, etc. Then you go back to the command line:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<myuser>/<myRepo>.git
git push -u origin master
```

And voila -- you have a git repo! However something isn't sitting right with me. After you issue this command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<myuser>/<myRepo>.git
```

Then my *understanding* is that your local repo is "connected to" (being tracked againt) the remote `master` branch of your remote GitHub repo (again: `https://github.com/<myuser>/<myRepo>.git`).

**So why do I then need `-u origin master` on the next command?** That is, why do I need my last command above to be `git push -u origin master`, and not just `git push`?! The local repo is "connected" to the remote master, right?! So why can't I just `git push` it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `git remote add...` just labels a remote URL.  It doesn't "connect" anything.   In particular, it doesn't make any association between your local branches and the remote branches.  This *only* happens on a per-branch basis (that is, it makes no sense to say that your *repository* is connected to another *repository*; you can only talk about tracking in terms of individual branches).  The tracking relationship is only set up when you `git checkout` a local branch corresponding to a remote branch, or when you explicitly set the tracking information with `-u` when running `git push`.

Consider a situation in which you have multiple remotes, e.g. you have run something like:

```
git remote add upstream ...
git remote add origin ...
git remote add anotherdeveloper ...
```

If you have a local branch named `master`, to which of those remotes should `git push` send your changes unless you tell git explicitly?

Comment: Though, to be fair to new users, if you have only *one* remote (which is pretty common) and you run `git push` with no arguments, it makes a lot of sense for Git to attempt to to push the current branch to the one remote, and set that up as the current branch's upstream. But Git isn't fair to new users. :-)

Comment: I was wondering about the -u just recently. Thanks for the concise explanation.